# How can I apply multiple transformation to the same key in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am an inventory manager, and my stock is as below

```
oldstock = {"A":100,"B":120,"C":150,"D":100,"E":230,"F":200,"G":180,"H":140,"I":90,"J":50}
```

I sold some items from each bin as below however (seems as though a list of dictionaries was the best way to represent it)

```
sale = [{"A":20},{"C":25},{"E":15},{"F":18},{"H":20},{"C":35},{"A":40},{"A":5},{"E":40},{"H":20}]
```

How can I calculate my new stock after making these sales per bin?

Comment: Have you considered codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: oh my I've never heard of that

Comment: Why don't you use `sale={'A':[20, 40, 5], ...}`?

Comment: Could you share more of your program? As I just told @Harshal Parekh, it may be possible to do this earlier in your program, which could simplify things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A cleaner, easy to understand approach would be something like this:

```
for item in sale:
    for k, v in item.items():
        # an extra check, you can remove this if you know for sure that sale will never have any key which is not in oldstock
        if k in oldstock:
            oldstock[k] = oldstock[k] - v

print(oldstock)
# {'A': 35, 'B': 120, 'C': 90, 'D': 100, 'E': 175, 'F': 182, 'G': 180, 'H': 100, 'I': 90, 'J': 50}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: this is lovely! thanks a lot, especially with the tuple unpacking style

Comment: You’re not going to mention anything about the list of dictionaries?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, there is nothing to mention, that's a part of the question.

Comment: @HarshalParekh So because it’s not directly part of the question, we shouldn’t discuss it? Is the point of this site not to learn and improve?

Comment: I did not say "it’s not directly part of the question", I said it is mentioned in the question and there is nothing to discuss on it, IMO. Furthermore, you may edit my answer if you have anything to share and I will be happy to approve the edit.